# Distributed SQL query performance in Apache Ignite

Tags: gridgain, ignite

I have defined following 2 classes Person(with PersonKey) and Company() with companyId as key. **PersonKey is affinity collocated with companyId**. Now I am trying to do **SQL distributed join (Person.companyId = Company.companyId)** on **2 nodes** connected in grid. I repeated same join with only **single node**. With distributed join in 2 nodes I should get 2x performance improvement, but it is performing worst with comparison to single node. Why is this happening? Are both nodes not participating in computation(here select query) part?

```
class PersonKey 
{
    // Person ID used to identify a person.
    private int personId;

    // Company ID which will be used for affinity.
    @AffinityKeyMapped
    private String companyId;

    public PersonKey(int personId, String companyId)
    {
        this.personId = personId;
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
            + ((companyId == null) ? 0 : companyId.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + personId;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        PersonKey other = (PersonKey) obj;
        if (companyId == null) {
            if (other.companyId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!companyId.equals(other.companyId))
            return false;
        if (personId != other.personId)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}




class Person
{
    @QuerySqlField(index = true)
    int personId;

    @QuerySqlField(index = true)
    String companyId;

    public Person(int personId, String companyId)
    {
        this.personId = personId;
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }

    private PersonKey key;
    public PersonKey key()
    {
        if(key == null)
            key = new PersonKey(personId, companyId);

        return key; 
    }
}



class Company
{
    @QuerySqlField(index = true)
    String companyId;

    String company_name;

    public Company(String CompanyId, String company_name)
    {
        this.companyId = CompanyId;
        this.company_name = company_name;
    }

    public String key()
    {
        return companyId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding second node does not automatically mean that the query will become twice faster. Moreover, it can easily become slower because network is added, while in a single node deployment all the data is local.

To make the test more fair you can run a query from a client node [1] and change the number of server nodes. In this case the result set will be always sent across the network and you will see the real difference in performance with different number of servers.

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/clients-vs-servers

Comment: Now I added client node as you suggested but still performance of running query on single server node is nearly same as 2 servers connected in grid. Query I have implemented is **SELECT c_discount, c_last, c_credit, w_tax FROM customer, warehouse WHERE w_id = ? AND c_w_id = w_id AND c_d_id = ? AND c_id = ?** with 150000 entries in customer table and 5 entries in warehouse table. Is it due to query is not that much compute intensive? or am I missing some performance settings?(For distributed join I have also considered affinity collocation)

Comment: I have also **disabled indexing** in tables to make searching process **compute intensive** but still grid with 1 server node is giving better output than grid with 2 servers.

Comment: If you have a small project that reproduces the issue, then I will be able to take a look. But generally, adding nodes can help only if there a lot of scans during the execution.

Comment: With indexing disabled(increased computation) now I got almost 2x perf improvement with 2 nodes. I think with indexing if databases are large then I might get improvement with more nodes.

Comment: I have one more question, what kind of distributed query or databases will give me more improvement with affinity collocation than without affinity collocation?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Which databases are you referring to? With Ignite you should always collocate as much as possible if you have joins in your queries. Non-collocated joins are also supported, but they are much slower, so should be used only in rare cases when there is no other option.